# Is there a way to extend iconv to support more encodings?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding

The `iconv` command is used to convert from one character encoding to another.  You can see the list of all the encodings it supports with `iconv -l`.

Is there a way to extend `iconv` by adding more supported encodings to it?  If so, could such extensions be published? Or is my only option to make changes to the code and go through the development process of `iconv` iteself?

Comment: What is the encoding that is missing?

Comment: @JJoao Don't ask lol....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `iconv` implementation comes from the GNU C library, then yes, [it is extensible](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/glibc-iconv-Implementation.html), in a couple of ways.

In the GNU C library, character set handling is implemented in loadable modules, which you’ll find as `.so` files in `/usr/lib/gconv` (or `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv`, or whatever `lib` directory your system uses). Which character set is handled by what module is describe in a text file, `/usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules`. Depending on your requirements, you can add a new module, and/or a new definition. In both cases, you’ll need to update the caches, using `iconvconfig`. You won’t need to get your changes integrated into the C library itself in order to distribute them.

The manual linked above provides more details.

Other implementations of [`iconv`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/iconv.html) may also be extensible; see your local documentation if you’re not using the GNU C library.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Linux and `glibc` , you can support additional encodings by create one or more sharable loadable `gconv` modules.

The default location for the `gconv` modules is `/usr/lib64/gconv` on 64-bit systems and `/usr/lib/gconv` on 32-bit systems.

See the `iconv(1)`, `iconv(3)` and `iconvconfig(8)` manpages for basic information.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/glibc-iconv-Implementation.html for details. An example of a conversion function framework is provided. Look at the `glibc` source code for working examples.